# convert git dump into local repo

Tags: git

I got a git dump which was originally exported from GitHub.
I can't know how they made the export but I have extracted the zip file and the structure of the files are as below.

`git status` from that folder returns with:
`On branch main nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Tried and didn't help:
`git clone exported_dir/ dst_dir/`

*I do expect to see in that repo some C# code files*

[image: image of the file structure on my local machine]

How can I convert them to the actual resources keeping all branches, history, logs, etc?

Comment: If you cd into that directory, and run `git status`, what does it show?

Comment: @NickODell ```On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean```

Comment: Then you are already set to go. A Git repository is just a directory hierarchy with a set of files. If you zip it up and unpack it elsewhere, that's usually all you need to do. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Can't understand. Where do I see the code files? I don't see them in this hierarchy. I do expect to see some C# files there

Comment: Perhaps your files are not in the `main` branch. Or perhaps they aren't there at all (if they were careless enough to not provide any instructions, perhaps they didn't even export it right).

Comment: If I change the remote to my local repo on github and push that there it worked and I was able to see the files. But locally I can't view them

Comment: The files that make up the project _won't_ be in there... you will be able to see them when you checkout a branch (or do a reset). Check the current state of stuff (current branch, what is going on) with `git status`. Given you have only _the repo_ (I would assume), git should say that you are working on some branch and _everything_ is missing.... if that is the case you can do a `git reset --hard` and you are setup to continue with all files in the working tree.

Comment: @eftshift0 the description is saying I have tried that approach already and shared the result of ```git status```

Comment: If the working tree is clean _and_ you have no files, then _perhaps_ you are on a commit that has... _nothing_. (unlikely but still possible)... or you are on an orphan branch? Check `git branch -a` and `git log --all --oneline --graph` if you have something there.

Comment: @eftshift0 running ```git branch``` retuned with branch "main" only. ```git log``` returned with ```<hash>(HEAD -> main) Initial commit```

Comment: that's all you got? That sounds like you got close to nothing in that repo. `git ls-tree -r main`. That should get you the list of files that makes up the tip of `main`.... also `git show --name-status main` should show you if there was something put in that first (and only) commit.

Comment: @eftshift0 probably they did provide a bad export. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you received a mixture of a bare and non-bare repository. Normally if you have files like `HEAD`, `config`, `packed-refs` it's already a repository (without a working tree).

You can try `git clone` locally from this directory to "un-bare" the repo:

```
git clone unzipped-dir/ somewhere-else/
```

Comment: It didn't help remain the same stracture and files